# How to show error messages from AD with UserPrinciple.ChangePassword()?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, change-password

I am trying to change a active directory user password through an application done by VB.net and the password is able to change when password policy is met but when I try to test it with a new password that does not satisfy the password policy, there is no error returned. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I have already tried using `DirectoryEntry` instead and even though that does show an error from AD when password policy isn't met, it does not change the password when password policy is met. This is the segment of the code:

```
Try
    Dim context As PrincipalContext = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "corp.contoso.com", "OU=Students,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=com")
    Dim userPrincipal As UserPrincipal = userPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, UserName)

    Using userPrincipal


        userPrincipal.ChangePassword(OldPassword, NewPassword)
        userPrincipal.Save()

        lreturnvalue = "Password successfully changed"

    End Using
Catch ex As Exception

    lreturnvalue = ex.InnerException.Message

End Try
```

Currently, I will be able to change the user's password if password policy requirements are met but no error is returned when it isn't met. Does anyone know why is this like that?

Comment: Maybe a little hacky, but why not both?  Use DirectoryEntry to validate the password, then if ok update it via userPrincipal?

Comment: @Hursey DirectoryEntry only returns the error message when I call for a Invoke("ChangePassword") so I can't really validate it before changing.